# как находить ошибку в инверсном коде при нечетном числе единичек в исходном коде?

Tags: алгоритм, передача-данных, обработка-сигналов

как находить ошибку в инверсном коде при нечетном числе единичек в исходном?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Также маленький вопрос: если получается сумма **11111** то ошибки нет? В теории об этом не написано.

**Вот теория:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В инверсном коде в вашем случае - когда среди всех 1 попадается один 0 - он и указывает на место ошибки, причем 0 среди единиц говорит, что ошибка - в основном сообщении, а не в контрольном. 1 среди нулей говорит о том, что ошибка - в контрольном сообщении.

11..11 у вас просто не может появиться.

Comment: не совсем понял почему "причем 0 среди единиц говорит, что ошибка - в основном сообщении" она же возможна и в контрольном, просто так и не скажешь же? ---> могло быть такое, что 11110 и 00001 вместо 11010 и 00101, разве нет?

Comment: потому что там получается четное кол-во единичек? есть ли какие-нибудь нормальные источники где про все это рассказано?

Comment: В контрольном на ошибку будет указывать единица среди нолей. Почитать... Ну, даже не подскажу, этим я интересовался лет 35 назад, с тех пор много новых идей и новой литературы, так что не подскажу :(

Comment: "В контрольном на ошибку будет указывать единица среди нолей" просто не совсем ясно почему

Comment: Ну так код построен - если кратко. Если длинно - попробуйте разные варианты, посмотрите, как работает с четным/нечетным числом единиц, с ошибкой в разных местах...

Comment: спасибо, посмотрю))